# SQLite - Return Rows Even If They Are Duplicates

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple SQLite table which has just one `ID` column.

I have some variable IDs that may be duplicates of each other like: `1,2,3,4,3,1` (These IDs are just examples, there could be hundreds of them).

And I have a simple query as follows:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID in (1,2,3,4,3,1)
```

In the usual case the answer contains only 4 rows with ids `1,2,3,4`. Is there any way to force SQLite to return rows in the order of the request (`1,2,3,4,3,1`) even if they are duplicates?

I have `n` IDs in my query and I want `n` rows in return even if they are duplicates.

Edit: The Table Definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY)
```

Comment: Please add your table definition.

Comment: @Fildor it's a really simple test table since I'm curious about the solution. I just added the definition.

Comment: PRIMARY KEYs need to be unique. You need another Column for the desired behavior. I am surprised it let you insert those rows at all.

Comment: They are distinct and I really don't have duplicate rows, I just want the returned rows to have a one to one mapping to the request : 4 rows for 4 IDs `1,2,3,1` of which the ID `1` is repeated twice in the request list.

Comment: Ah, ok. I misunderstood. In that case, I'd duplicate the data not in the db / query but in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join`:

```
select t.*
from (select 1 as id, 1 as ord union all
      select 2 as id, 2 as ord union all
      select 3 as id, 3 as ord union all
      select 4 as id, 4 as ord union all
      select 3 as id, 5 as ord union all
      select 1 as id, 6 as ord
     ) ids left join
     t
     on t.id = ids.id
order by ids.ord;
```

Comment: Thanks, but there may be hundreds of IDs and I can't make static queries like the one you proposed.

Comment: @Cypher . . . (1) Yes, you can put hundreds of ids into a derived table.  (2) You are planning on putting them into an `IN` clause anyway.  (3) If the ids are in a table already, just use that.